# Why does this query return "incorrect" results?

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables:

'CouponType' table:

```
 AutoID         Code        Name

    1         CouT001     SunCoupon     
    2         CouT002     GdFriCoupon     
    3         CouT003     1for1Coupon
```

'CouponIssued' table:

```
 AutoID              CouponNo        CouponType_AutoID  

    1                 Co001               1 
    2                 Co002               1
    3                 Co003               1                   
    4                 Co004               2
    5                 Co005               2 
    6                 Co006               2
```

'CouponUsed' table:

```
  AutoID     Coupon_AutoID

    1              2  
    2              3  
    3              5
```

I am trying to join 3 tables together using this query below but apparently I am not getting right values for CouponIssued column:

```
select CouponType.AutoID, Code, Name, Count(CouponIssued.CouponType_AutoID), count(CouponUsed.Coupon_AutoID)
from (CouponType left join CouponIssued
on (CouponType.AutoID = CouponIssued.CouponType_AutoID))
left join CouponUsed
on  (couponUsed.Coupon_AutoID = CouponIssued.AutoID)
group by CouponType.AutoID, code, name
order by code
```

The expected result should be like:

```
**Auto ID         Code           Name             Issued            used**

1                 CouT001       SunCoupon           3                  2

2                 CouT002       GdFriCoupon         3                  1

3                 CouT003       1for1Coupon         0                  0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.AutoID
      ,t.Code
      ,t.Name
      ,count(i.CouponType_AutoID) AS issued
      ,count(u.Coupon_AutoID) AS used
FROM   CouponType t
LEFT   JOIN CouponIssued i ON i.CouponType_AutoID = t.AutoID
LEFT   JOIN CouponUsed u ON u.Coupon_AutoID = i.AutoID
GROUP  BY 1,2,3;
```

You might consider using less confusing names for your table columns. I have made very good experiences with using the **same name for the same data** across tables (as far as sensible).

In your example, `AutoID` is used for three different columns, two of which appear a second time in another table under a different name. This *would* still make sense if `Coupon_AutoID` was named `CouponIssued_AutoID` instead.

Answer (score 0):

change `count(Coupon.CouponType_AutoID)` to `count(CouponIssued.CouponType_AutoID)` and `count(Coupon.Coupon_AutoID)` to `count(CouponUsed.Coupon_AutoID)`